# No session repository could be auto-configured(session store type is 'redis')

Tags: java, session, spring-security, redis

I am following the spring security tutorial from this [link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_login_page_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_ii) on that tutorial third part. I have to use redis to hand away session information to resource backend.

Here my applicaiton.yml file:

```
server:
  port: 9000
security:
  sessions: NEVER
spring:
  session:
    store-type: redis
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework:
      security: DEBUG
      session: TRACE
```

Also, I use HeaderHttpSessionStrategy bean as a session strategy

```
@Bean
HeaderHttpSessionStrategy sessionStrategy() {
    return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
}
```

My pom couldn't find the related class declaration and give me

**package org.springframework.session.web.http does not exist**

Above error Here my pom.xml file.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am new in spring and spring-security world. Can any advice solve this problem?

Edit:

After I added the new dependency in pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I solve the above problem but this time hit me the new one it says:

**No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'redis'**

My redis configuration on application.yml is above. And I am using redis on docker. My docker yml is:

```
 redis:
     image: redis
     ports:
         - "6379:6379"
```

Comment: What have you done to try to find the maven artifact which contains that package?

Comment: Hello I tries to add
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
This dependency after that I could add the related class but this time gives me configuration error from redis.

Comment: Then ask a question about the redis problem, if you cannot solve it. It sounds as though you have already fixed this problem.

Answer (score 7):

I got this error recently. I was using Spring Boot 2.4.0. I had added the dependency for Spring Session, but forgot to add one for Jedis.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

When I first deployed, with that it gave me the message:

```
No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'redis')
```

After I added this dependency and rebuilt my JAR, everything worked.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Perhaps that will help someone else.

Comment: Hello, Daniel currently I didn't continue the project but when I do I will give it a try and revert back to you thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yup that fixes it.